# SQL returning all rows and count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have 3 tables, Property managers, Addresses and Units. I'm trying to get all the rows using the aggregate function COUNT, but it only returns 1 row.

I want to get all the addresses where pmNo = 1 and the total count of units for each address. My SQl query is like this:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(u.unitId) AS totalUnits
FROM Units AS u
JOIN Addresses AS a ON a.addressNo = u.addressNo
JOIN PropertyManagers AS pm ON pm.pmNo = a.pmNo
WHERE pm.pmNo = 1
```

This gives me the result of:

```
addressNo     city     province     postalCode     buildingName     pmNo     totalUnits
1             city1      prov1          V9F3b6     building1 Apt.   1            3
```

Which is right but it only gives me the first address fields then combines both the addresses units into the total units.

I want the result to be:

```
addressNo     city     province     postalCode     buildingName     pmNo     totalUnits
1             city1      prov1          V9F3b6     building1 Apt.   1            2
2             city2      prov2          V0N1U8     building2 Apt.   1            1
```

Comment: Actually, the query is `incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` as it is but if it's turned off, then a `GROUP BY` on any of the column that have different value should return your expected result. With `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` turned on, you'll need to `GROUP BY addressNo, city, province, postalCode, buildingName, pmNo` for the query to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation functions like `COUNT` for non-simple cases need to specify the aggregation that is happen. In your case, you want the addresses. As `addressNo` is the primary key and the easiest identifier of a unique address use the `GROUP BY` of the query:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(u.unitId) AS totalUnits
FROM Units AS u
JOIN Addresses AS a ON a.addressNo = u.addressNo
JOIN PropertyManagers AS pm ON pm.pmNo = a.pmNo
WHERE pm.pmNo = 1
GROUP BY a.addressNo
```

Comment: Totally forgot about GROUP BY, that was the answer. Like FanoFN said, my SQL Workbench version is older so it wasn't throwing me an error about not having a GROUP BY as well.

Comment: `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` can be set in the Workbench session or on a test server to show these errors until you're ready to make it the default on production. Happy SQLing.